# Dock/Taskbar Shortcuts to switch between OS

Tags: boot, windows, grub, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to try to figure out a way to create a single click icon to go on my Pop OS dock and Windows 10 taskbar that, when clicked, immediately restarts into the opposite OS. I'm trying to slim down the relatively painful dualboot experience to encourage myself to use Linux more- as at the moment switching between OS is such a massive pain I never do, and the gaming/photoshop problem prevents me from being able to switch fully.

I think it should be possible, via:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/grub-reboot.8.html

something like:

```
sudo grub-reboot 4
sudo reboot now
```

However, on the windows side, I'm coming up a bit blank. I'm hoping it may be possible via the windows subsystem for linux. Is this at all possible, or am I putting myself through pointless wasted time pursuing this?

Edit: Alternatively, switching back to and using easyBCD, it seems possible from the windows side. Would there be any way to create a BCD shortcut from the linux side?

Comment: This seems like a question that needs to be asked on [su], not here.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found on Ubuntu Stack Exchange, although not worth the amount of time this would cost to set up:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/635205/link-to-restart-from-windows-to-ubuntu